# Discord (JDA) get the HTTP response headers for rate limits

Tags: java, rate-limiting, discord-jda

Discord has different rate limits for the different types of requests.
50 / 1s as the global limit or 2 / 10m for channel name changes and so on.
However, except the global limit, these limits aren't documented. The documentation states that we need to take a look at the response headers for more details because the rate limits are subject to change and shouldn't be hard coded anyway.
Now I can't find how to access the returned headers via JDA to get the rate limits. Has anyone an idea how I would do this?
Also I don't know much about the HTTP stuff but I'll figure it out.

What I need this for:
I just made a practical tool for a game. It is similar to a checklist and depending on user inputs it calculates stuff the user can use ingame. It's a DM with buttons where the DM is edited everytime you click a button. This tool can be shared with up to 3 more team mates. Where all DMs are edited in the same way so everyone sees the results and the buttons that have been clicked.

The problem is: As soon as someone with 2 or 3 team mates clicks a lot of buttons we get 429 warnings.

```
> [JDA RateLimit-Worker 2] WARN RateLimiter - Encountered 429 on route Route[PATCH](route=channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id})
```

With bucket, channel id and retry time.

I changed it to only update the messages once every 3 seconds and only if anyone has clicked a button. So it won't edit these messages more often just because someone spams buttons. Now we have a maximum of 1 edit each in 4 private channels every 3 seconds per team. (However with a lot of teams using it at the same time we would need to edit 1 message each in maybe 20 or more channels at roughly the same time)

We still get 429 warnings with even only 1 team of 3 users.
It looks like there is a pretty low rate limit for editing private messages that is shared for ALL private channels.

I can't really move this tool to e.g. threads in guilds because it's used across 70 servers now and it would easily spam create channels/threads and also would need permissions to manage channels or threads.

If I just knew more about the rate limit I could solve the problem...

Comment: If you would use the latest version of JDA you could see the exact retry-after and scope in the logs.